# Which Countries accept Stateless Person Certificate as travelling document for Visa

Tags: visas, stateless-persons

Please someone can help with the list of countries who grant tourist visa for Stateless Person Certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every country that grants tourist visas well do so for those holding a stateless person's travel document, but for those countries where there is a genuine application process, the person must apply and, like all other visa applicants, must meet the qualifying criteria to be granted a visa.

Comment: It might be worth adding that stateless person may have a bit harder time to prove their strong connection to home country and intent to really leave country he/she is applying to visit.